# Android Camera with DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-camera, android-dialogfragment

I'm trying to construct a DialogFragment that allows a guy take people and remove them. I already open the camera inside of it and take pictures.

However, I need to set each thumb to the left squares. And the first one go to the big square, and when a thumb is clicked, it is displayed on the big square.

Could someone help me? Below is the code:

```
public class FotosFragment extends DialogFragment {

private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
Uri fileUri = null;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_fotos_fragment, container);

    ImageView picture01 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.picture01);
    ImageView picture02 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.picture02);
    ImageView picture03 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.picture03);

    getDialog().setTitle("DialogFragment Tutorial");

    picture01.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
        }
    });

    picture02.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
        }
    });

    picture03.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
        }
    });

    return view;

}

}
```

And here is the layout sample: [image]

Comment: you only have 3 images in your layout. or you will have N Number of images?

Comment: only 3, not more than it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i understand your problem. after capturing the picture you want to show pictures in big box right? for this you need to set some flag for picture01, picture02 and picture03 that if the picture has already been taken then you offcourse you want to dispaly inside big box. now you need to something like this

```
boolean isPictue01isTaken = false;

picture01.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
             if(isPictue01isTaken){
//              show image 01 in big box here. if bigbox is your imageview then set image bitmap that you already captured,
             }else {
                    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
                    isPictue01isTake = true;
             }
        }
});
```

Comment: So, I got that part! But, how I can get the picture as I don't have the method "onActivityResult", I only know how to get using that.

Comment: you need to implement that part.. without onActivityResult you can not get result from camera

Comment: Is it possible inside a dialogFragment?

Comment: i think yes.. but i never tried this.. give it a try. please

Comment: Yes, I will! Thank you. And, if it works, I will post here =D

Comment: Hello Mustanser, I find a way to get the images, and pass them to the big box. Have anyway to check when I take a picture if the big box is null ? Because if it is, I will set the taken image.

Comment: you can set a flag for big box as well